# Remove nonspecific character and a space in SQL string

Tags: sql, string, replace, space

I need to clean up some records in an SQL table. Somehow the middle initial was placed in front of some last names in the last name field.

The table looks like this:

```
EmplyID   last_name_field
123       A Smith
456       Jones
789       J Gillum
```

Not all of the records have a middle initial and space in front of them. I can't use TRIM to take away the first two characters in each of the records because it would mess up the ones whose last names where correctly imported. Is there a way to remove the first character and space for the only the records that have the middle initial?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes there is! You could use CASE WHEN to check for the existence of SUBSTRING(last_name_field, 2, 1)='  ' and do some more string manipulation from there. Seeing in how you didnt try anything, I figure id give you half of the solution and let you try from that starting point :)

Comment: In theory, this can't be done, because there are last names that begin with a single character followed by a space. In practice though, it depends on your data (and how well you know it). Start by searching the names containing a space, if that's a manageable number of rows, you can check whether those are all (or actually all of those) that you are looking for to correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution. Just remove everything before the space. I was on the right track with TRIM instead use RIGHT and LEN

update TABLE_NAME
Set COLUMN_NAME = RIGHT(COLUMN_NAME, LEN(COLUMN_NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', COLUMN_NAME))
where CHARINDEX(' ', COLUMN_NAME) > 0